# Correct way to convert queue emitting Take[_, A] to A?

Tags: scala, zio, zio-streams

I don't quite understand the user-level design of ZIO's ZStream when writing to a queue:

```
  val queue: RIO[Scope, Dequeue[Take[Nothing, Int]]] =
    ZStream(1, 2).toQueue()
```

... emitting (for example) `Take(Success(Chunk(1)))`

I understand that, at a low level, something like this is necessary as a way of expressing completions & errors as data types.  But this seems a bit cumbersome at the user level.  Is there some way I'm supposed to be unwrapping these into plain elements?

It looks like `Take#done` might be part of the puzzle:

```
  def done[R](implicit trace: Trace): ZIO[R, Option[E], Chunk[A]] =
    ZIO.done(exit)
```

But I feel like there's probably some utility lying around somewhere, which I'm seeing, which knows how to unwrap the resulting `Option[E]` into an `E`, and the `Chunk[A]` so that each result-consumption operation can just deal with a single `A`.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what data type you have as input and how you want to process it. Maybe you could provide a pseudo code of what you'd like to have.

Comment: Thank you, Gaël J.  For the code example above, I'd like to know the idiomatic way to simply read an ```Int```.  (Or any other type ```A``` which is being emitted wrapped in ```Take[_, A]```)

Comment: Put another way, I would have simply expected there to be something like ```.toQueue()``` which yielded a ```Dequeue[..., Int]``` -- or a utility for more easily unwrapping a ```Take```, much like what ```.flattenExitOption``` does for streams.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of research and experimentation I've learned some things.  These might not be optimal (will leave this open for a while to see if others add helpful answers), but they seem okay for the moment.

One solution is to use `ZStream#toQueueOfElements()`, which instead yields `Dequeue[Exit[Option[Nothing], A]]`.  This isn't quite like being able to do an `.await` on a `Dequeue[A]`, but it's a little bit better -- for an element (a) you can do:

```
a match {
  case Exit.Success(value) => ???
  case Exit.Failure(cause) => ???
}
```